How to create a sleep stage graph in Android similar to Apple Health's ot Google Fit's visualization?
I have checked many popular libraries like MPAndroidChart, AnyChart-Android but they don't have a similar built-in chart like these ones:
Apple:

Google:

I have also tried to customize some of their charts but it's tricky because columns need to support multiple data ranges so I could not really have a good progress and do not have a code to share.
Any ideas or directions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

I would think of those as timelines, not charts. That said, my guess is that you will need to write your own rendering code for such a timeline, drawing to a Canvas via a custom View or a composable.
